# Kubernetes ImagePullSecrets Failing with ImagePullBackOff: failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs: unexpected media type text/html

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

When I try to create a pod ,pulling image from Harbor,here is the error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  35s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned test/test-pod to ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-ams3-01-slave01
  Normal   Pulling    18s (x2 over 34s)  kubelet            Pulling image "harbor.com/test/backend2:v2"
  Warning  Failed     18s (x2 over 34s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "harbor.com/test/backend2:v2": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "harbor.com/test/backend2:v2": failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs: unexpected media type text/html for sha256:fb4c5f9259d39df93df43fb58ca7aef53a217636ac00ee3c68c26db5df04706d: not found
  Warning  Failed     18s (x2 over 34s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    3s (x2 over 33s)   kubelet            Back-off pulling image "harbor.com/test/backend2:v2"
  Warning  Failed     3s (x2 over 33s)   kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

My pod yaml file here:

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
  namespace: test
spec:
  containers:
  - image: harbor.com/test/backend:v2
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: test-container
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: harbor5
```

My secret file here:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: eyJhdXRocyI6eyJoYXJib3IuY29tIjp7InVzZXJuYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IkhhcmJvcjEyMzQ1IiwiZW1haWwiOiIxMDc0NzU0NzYzQHFxLmNvbSIsImF1dGgiOiJZV1J0YVc0NlNHRnlZbTl5TVRJek5EVT0ifX19
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-07-20T11:34:12Z"
  name: harbor5
  namespace: test
  resourceVersion: "816707"
  uid: d2822fed-44ef-4cf4-a0d7-9aa53c8afada
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

I don't know what's wrong with my image,its' source file is a springboot.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk

WORKDIR /root

ADD target/*.jar app.jar

ENV JVM_OPTS=""

CMD java ${JVM_OPTS} \
    -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom \
    -jar app.jar
```

And bash command here:

```
set -eu

IMG_REGISTRY="harbor.com/test" 
IMG_NAME="backend2"
IMG_TAG="v2"    

docker build -t ${IMG_NAME}:${IMG_TAG} .

docker tag ${IMG_NAME}:${IMG_TAG} ${IMG_REGISTRY}/${IMG_NAME}:${IMG_TAG}

docker push ${IMG_REGISTRY}/${IMG_NAME}:${IMG_TAG}

docker rmi ${IMG_REGISTRY}/${IMG_NAME}:${IMG_TAG}
```

Meanwhile, I can execute

```
docker login harbor.com
docker pull harbor.com/test/backend:v2
```

It can successfully pull it, and 'docker image' can also show it:

```
REPOSITORY                 TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
harbor.com/test/backend2   v2        6ae6c9c165d2   12 hours ago    493MB
harbor.com/test/backend    v1        178682241b96   5 days ago      493MB
nginx                      1.18.0    c2c45d506085   15 months ago   133MB
```

Any idea where I am going wrong ?

Comment: "failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs: unexpected media type text/html" : check the harbor address tp the image, docker is trying to unpack an html page

Comment: Thanks for your comment!The address 'harbor.com' is my harbor registry, I modify my /etd/hosts file to parse 'harbor.com' to my harbor server's IP.I don't know what's wrong with it,what should I do to make the docker recognize it as an image of this registry?BTW,my harbor IP is 165.232.155.195, am I supposed to use that instead of 'harbor.com' ? @Kartoch